# detecting dotted line in road using OpenCv python

Tags: python, opencv

i want to detect dotted line on road, i'm making code but something wrong  i could not expecting result please help me, its something not detecting dotted line(break line) in road

Here is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def classify_road_marking(length, orientation, position):


    if orientation == "horizontal":
        orientation_type = "White Dotted"
    else:
        orientation_type = "Other"

    if position in ["middle of lane", "on shoulder"]:
        position_type = "White Dotted"
    else:
        position_type = "Other"

    if  orientation_type == position_type == "White Dotted":
        return "White Dotted"
    else:
        return "Other"


# Load an image (replace 'road_image.jpg' with your image file)
image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/user/Desktop/dash1.jpeg')

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply edge detection using Canny
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150)

# Find contours in the edge-detected image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Loop over the contours to classify road markings
for contour in contours:
    # Calculate properties of the contour
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    length = max(w, h)

    # Filter out small contours (adjust the threshold as needed)
    if length < 20:
        continue

    orientation = "horizontal" if w > h else "vertical"
    position = "middle of lane" if y > image.shape[0] / 2 else "on shoulder"

    classification = classify_road_marking(length, orientation, position)

    # Draw a bounding box and label the classification on the image
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(image, classification, (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Display the annotated image
cv2.imshow("Classified Road Markings", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[its result my](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSLSY.jpg) 
i want only detect dotted line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dashed(dotted) line detection opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76930487/dasheddotted-line-detection-opencv)